# How select a certain date range when R Shiny object is opened (using dateRangelist)?

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following UI code, which helps me to select many periods of time from 2016 to 2020. However, I wanted that when the file is firstly opened the date range is between Today-14 days and Today, I tried it by using as.Date(Sys.Date()-14) in min/start, however it does not work. Could you help?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Day-ahead prices"),
  
  # Sidebar with slider input to select date range
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Add a Slider Input to select date range
      #sliderInput
      dateRangeInput("Date_range_selector", "Select Date Range",
                     start = as.Date("2016-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                     end = as.Date("2020-12-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                     
                     #min = as.Date("2020-10-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                     #max = as.Date("2020-12-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
                     #value=c(as.Date(Sys.Date()-14),as.Date(Sys.Date())),
                     #format ="%Y-%m-%d" ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work, you probably have the problem somewhere else. Here I show you the html that is built when you add `Sys.Date()-14` to the code. Take a look at `data-initial-date` at the first `<input ....>` line.

Also, same thing is used as an example in `?shiny::dateRangeInput` doc file. Try running a sample shiny app with such selector and see if it works

```
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2020-10-14"
> shiny::dateRangeInput("Date_range_selector", "Select Date Range",
+                start = as.Date(Sys.Date()-14,"%Y-%m-%d"),
+                end = as.Date("2020-12-01","%Y-%m-%d"))
<div id="Date_range_selector" class="shiny-date-range-input form-group shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" for="Date_range_selector">Select Date Range</label>
  <div class="input-daterange input-group">
    <input class="input-sm form-control" type="text" data-date-language="en" data-date-week-start="0" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date-start-view="month" data-initial-date="2020-09-30" data-date-autoclose="true"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon"> to </span>
    <input class="input-sm form-control" type="text" data-date-language="en" data-date-week-start="0" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date-start-view="month" data-initial-date="2020-12-01" data-date-autoclose="true"/>
  </div>
</div>
```